# Android: Python errors when downloading source via Cygwin

Tags: android, cygwin, repository

I am receiving the following errors when I attempt to download the Gingerbread source using "repo" in Cygwin.

Everything runs fine until I perform a "repo sync" command:

```
    7 [unknown (0x175C)] python 4232 fork: child 8044 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
85124 [unknown (0x1430)] python 4232 fork: child 6932 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
175810 [unknown (0xF38)] python 4232 fork: child 4536 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
266256 [unknown (0x8AC)] python 4232 fork: child 7564 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 186, in _FetchHelper
current_branch_only=opt.current_branch_only)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/project.py", line 910, in Sync_NetworkHalf
self._InitRemote()
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1690, in _InitRemote
remote = self.GetRemote(self.remote.name)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/project.py", line 612, in GetRemote
return self.config.GetRemote(name)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 173, in GetRemote
r = Remote(self, name)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 525, in __init__
self.url = self._Get('url')
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 656, in _Get
return self._config.GetString(key, all = all)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 114, in GetString
v = self._cache[_key(name)]
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 231, in _cache
self._cache_dict = self._Read()
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 237, in _Read
d = self._ReadGit()
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 288, in _ReadGit
d = self._do('--null', '--list')
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 312, in _do
capture_stderr = True)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_command.py", line 215, in __init__
raise GitError('%s: %s' % (command[1], e))
GitError: config: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 186, in _FetchHelper
current_branch_only=opt.current_branch_only)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/project.py", line 910, in Sync_NetworkHalf
self._InitRemote()
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1690, in _InitRemote
remote = self.GetRemote(self.remote.name)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/project.py", line 612, in GetRemote
return self.config.GetRemote(name)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 173, in GetRemote
r = Remote(self, name)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 525, in __init__
self.url = self._Get('url')
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 656, in _Get
return self._config.GetString(key, all = all)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 114, in GetString
v = self._cache[_key(name)]
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 231, in _cache
self._cache_dict = self._Read()
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 237, in _Read
d = self._ReadGit()
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 288, in _ReadGit
d = self._do('--null', '--list')
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 312, in _do
capture_stderr = True)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_command.py", line 215, in __init__
raise GitError('%s: %s' % (command[1], e))
GitError: config: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 186, in _FetchHelper
current_branch_only=opt.current_branch_only)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/project.py", line 910, in Sync_NetworkHalf
self._InitRemote()
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1690, in _InitRemote
remote = self.GetRemote(self.remote.name)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/project.py", line 612, in GetRemote
return self.config.GetRemote(name)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 173, in GetRemote
r = Remote(self, name)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 525, in __init__
self.url = self._Get('url')
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 656, in _Get
return self._config.GetString(key, all = all)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 114, in GetString
v = self._cache[_key(name)]
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 231, in _cache
self._cache_dict = self._Read()
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 237, in _Read
d = self._ReadGit()
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 288, in _ReadGit
d = self._do('--null', '--list')
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 312, in _do
capture_stderr = True)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_command.py", line 215, in __init__
raise GitError('%s: %s' % (command[1], e))
GitError: config: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 186, in _FetchHelper
current_branch_only=opt.current_branch_only)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/project.py", line 910, in Sync_NetworkHalf
self._InitRemote()
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1690, in _InitRemote
remote = self.GetRemote(self.remote.name)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/project.py", line 612, in GetRemote
return self.config.GetRemote(name)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 173, in GetRemote
r = Remote(self, name)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 525, in __init__
self.url = self._Get('url')
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 656, in _Get
return self._config.GetString(key, all = all)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 114, in GetString
v = self._cache[_key(name)]
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 231, in _cache
self._cache_dict = self._Read()
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 237, in _Read
d = self._ReadGit()
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 288, in _ReadGit
d = self._do('--null', '--list')
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_config.py", line 312, in _do
capture_stderr = True)
File "/home/David/.repo/repo/git_command.py", line 215, in __init__
raise GitError('%s: %s' % (command[1], e))
GitError: config: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable


error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

Can anyone advise what the problem may be here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I wonder if it is related to the issues described here:
http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.using.html#faq.using.bloda

It certainly seems like "random fork failures" might be the cause, but I'm not sure how to identify which Windows software might be the problem; nothing on that list jumps out at me.

Comment: I just tried again in "Safe Mode with Networking" (Win7 Pro 32-bit) and the same errors occur, so the interfering Windows plug-ins explanation now seems less plausible.

Comment: Also tried downgrading to Python 2.6.5 and running "rebaseall", still the same problem.

Comment: Having tried rebaseall with a variety of different base addresses to no effect, I've now given up on trying to get this working with cygwin and am using a Linux virtual machine instead (which is not without its problems either but that's another story.)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
repo sync -j1
```

I think multithreading is not supported in Cygwin.